# How do I connect my NetXtreme BCM5755M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express in y Dell latitude d630?

Tags: 13.04, wireless, networking, drivers, dell

Trying to get my `09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5755M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)` working with my wifi. I just installed Raring Ringtail on this dell latitude D630 and I can't get it to connect without a wifi dongle.

This is what I got when I typed `sudo lshw -c network`:

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5755M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:21:70:98:04:32
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.128 firmware=5755m-v3.29 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:44 memory:fe8f0000-fe8fffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@2:1
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 7c:dd:90:11:a0:10
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=3.8.0-31-generic firmware=0.29 ip=10.0.0.8 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Also, when I go to additional drivers in the software and updates settings, no proprietary drivers show up.

I've tried `sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer` because it worked on a bunch of old Dell laptops that I converted over before, but it didn't work on this one.  Is this driver even compatible with wifi?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Last week, I installed a Broadcom BCM5755M WLAN card onto my Dell Latitude D630, along with a 320 Gb hard drive and the 64-bit version of Trusty.  I don't remember having to reinstall the b43 drivers, but I am able to connect to wireless networks.  I would like to figure out how to get wireless-N download speeds, though.

Answer (score 0):

The BCM5755M is the wired ethernet controller, not the wireless one. The only way you'll get it to work is to plug in an ethernet cable.

The WiFi controller in a D620 or D630 is on a daughterboard, and can come several manufacturers. Hopefully you have the Intel one, which shows in `lspci` as:

```
0c:00.00 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection (rev 02)
```